# Connecting to AWS Aurora Serverless with Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hikaricp, amazon-aurora

Trying to connect a Spring Boot container to an Aurora Serverless database. Here's what works:

- Connecting the container to a provisioned Aurora database
- Connecting to the serverless database from my computer via `psql`

However, when I configure the database connection parameters for the serverless database and start the container, I get the following error:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    ...
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableGSSEncrypted(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:436) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar!/:42.2.16]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Here's what I've tried (per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205733/aws-aurora-serverless-spring-boot-communication-link-error)):

- Adjusting the Hikari connection parameters (does not seem to do anything):

```
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=0
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
    spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=90000
    spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=90000
```

- Lazy bean initialization (seems to reduce the amount of time before the connection times out):

```
    spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

My computer is a WorkSpace in a peering VPC, so the VPC shouldn't be an issue. Additionally, I'm having the same problem when I boot the container in an ECS cluster within the VPC. Any help would be appreciated - I've been researching this for weeks.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work adding `?gssEncMode=disable` to the jdbc url.

ex: `jdbc:postgresql://dev-aurora-postgres-serverless.cluster-xxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/my_db?gssEncMode=disable`

Comment: You are a blessing - I've been banging my head against this for weeks. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had to look at the class `ConnectionFactoryImpl` of the Postgres JDBC driver to try understand what was happening. Looks like a non-standard response from Aurora-Serverless. Probably they will solve the issue on their side in the future.